# IBM Connections - Wikis and Files extraction from database

Tags: sql, ibm-connections, hcl-connections

I need to extract the wiki html content for a specific community and I have access only to the database.
Starting from the table  wikis.library table and connecting it with the wikis.media  i'm able to retrieve the data,summary but not the html content.
Where is the html content of a wiki page saved?

Thanks.

Comment: You should create a reprex to enhance your chances to receive appropriate support from the community. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

It's saved on the file share. File share is configured in the WebSphere Environment variable WIKIS_CONTENT_DIR. Read the revision from MEDIA_REVISION table and extract the file name of the page on the file share via the MEDIA_FILE_ID field.

You can probably also use the Wiki API to retrieve the content https://ds_infolib.hcltechsw.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Retrieving_a_wiki_page_ic50&content=apicontent